# C/C++ intrinsic for assembly VMOVD

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, vectorization, sse

How (in C/C++) to load 32-bit integer to the low 32 bits of an SSE register, while leaving the rest undefined? I mean something like `vmovd xmm0, eax` with the same efficiency.

Comment: `vmovd = _mm_cvtsi32_si128` but I guess you know that, so why wouldn't that be appropriate?

Comment: @harold, I didn't know about it, thanks!

Comment: In Intel's intrinsics guide, you could search for `(int ` to find intrinsics where the first parameter is an `int` or `int *`.  (See the [sse tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info) for links).  Or you could search for `movd` to find intrinsics for `movd`, in the intrinsics guide or Intel's insn ref manual: http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVD:MOVQ.html

Comment: @PeterCordes [here](http://www.officedaytime.com/simd512e/simd.html) too, did you know that place btw? Might be useful

Comment: @harold: oh cool, thanks for that link.  Added to the x86 and SSE tag wikis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you are looking for the intrinsic `_mm_cvtsi32_si128 (int a)`. This copies the lower 32 bits. The upper bits are set to zero.